# Many to many hibernate mapping and intermediate table object

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping, many-to-many

How can I define  a many to many relationship in hibernate where the intermediate table maps to a object? I.e.
Build can have another build as dependency and this dependency can be selected in other builds too. The 'build dependency' object should look something like:

```
BuildDep{
   int id;
   Build parent;
   Build child;
   ....
}
```

mapping to the intermediate table having columns:

```
id, child_build_id, parent_build_id
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, many-to-many associations can only be used when the association table does not have any other columns besides the foreign keys to the parent tables.

Instead, you should use two ManyToOne/OneToMany associations.

Here's a forum topic on this subject (with an example):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/218431/ORM/databases/Hibernate-Annotations-many-many-association